# Play framework 2.1.x won't compile Twitter Bootstrap 3 LESS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, playframework-2.1, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to setup a Play framework 2.1.1 with Twitter Bootstrap 3 using the LESS files.

I've put the bootstrap LESS files into `app\assets\stylesheets\bootstrap`.

I've update my project configuration (`Build.scala`), in order to compile only the main `bootstrap.less` file (importing the other files) :

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(customLessEntryPoints),
    javascriptEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(customJavascriptEntryPoints)
)

def customLessEntryPoints(base: File): PathFinder = (
    (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" / "bootstrap" / "bootstrap.less") +++
    (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" / "*.less")
)

def customJavascriptEntryPoints(base: File): PathFinder = (
  (base / "app" / "assets" / "javascripts" * "*.js")
)
```

I can't manage to compile Bootstrap, I get the following :

```
Expected )
In ...\app\assets\stylesheets\bootstrap\mixins.less at line 0.
```

The problem seems to come from the mixin parameters separed by semicolons. When I replace these semicolons by commas it works.

Does the Play LESS compiler need commas ? Do I need to replace every semicolon by comma or can I configure Play LESS compiler ?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

There is an official issue here : https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1423

It seems that i need to wait for an upgrade of Play with a new version of LESS compiler. I'll be using an external compiler meanwhile.

Comment: please add your edit as an answer for your own question (and accept it)

Comment: same issue :) wait also :)

Comment: I read the Edit but can't find the solution. Someone can explain? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a temporary solution posted by the guy mica16 from [github](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1423#issuecomment-22510265):

1) I installed the plugin following the documentation: https://github.com/jmparsons/play-lessc (there's an error in the example shown => the command must be: `npm install -g less` and not `npm install -g lessc`).

2) In the plugins.sbt, I added these lines :

```
resolvers += "JMParsons Releases" at "http://jmparsons.github.io/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.jmparsons" % "play-lessc" % "0.0.8")
```

(make sure you separate them by a line jump)

3) I opened my build.scala and I inserted the lines specified by the plugins and add these:

```
def customLessEntryPoints(base: File): PathFinder =
(base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" * "bootstrap.less") +++
(base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" * "main.less") (main.less is my custom css)
```

For a reason I can't define (I don't even seek for it for now), you should place your bootstrap less files directly in the stylesheets root folder. Otherwise, I couldn't make those file compile.

4) I specified the html line concerning the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")">
```

5) I run `play run` and the whole worked.

**Edit** - As someone asked: is there a way to install lessc plugin without installing jsnode and npm?